# Typescript import folder

Tags: node.js, typescript

What is the approach to import all the modules from the given folder?

I've read in excellent basarat's "Beginning node.js" book that I can create index file in the folder and make all imports in it.

As an example my index.ts file (located in "common" folder):

```
import * as moduleA from './moduleA';
import * as moduleB from './moduleB';
```

And an example of my app.ts file:

```
import * as common from './common/index';
```

But this approach doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the files are only being imported into `index.ts`, but they are not being exported.

To fix this, you can change the import statements to export statements:

```
export * from './moduleA';
export * from './moduleB';
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there is an export instead of import option. Now it works.

Comment: There are really not any plugins or any other options? Just this making an index file in a nobrainer manner?